# Latitude and Longitude return Null

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to print the latitude and longitude, along with accelerometer readings in my application. However, when I try to use the latitude and longitude from my GPS class in my Main Activity class, it always returns null. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried countless different approaches (the internet is full of them), but none seem to resolve my problem. Thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.explorer.extractor;

//import packages

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener,OnClickListener {

    GPSTracker gps;

    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    private static final String FILENAME = "newgps.txt"; //file where data is written


    //layout variables
    TableLayout t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize sensor manager
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        //initialize accelerometer
        accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        //mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        t1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy){}

    /**onResume() registers the accelerometer for listening
     * to the events
     */
    /*
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }
    */
    /*
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    */

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
       //if sensor status result is unreliable return
        if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE){
            return;
        }

        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

        //check sensor type
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            //assign directions
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            try {
                //write to text file the x, y, and z values each type a sensor detects change
                writeToFile(Float.toString(x), Float.toString(y), Float.toString(z));
                Log.i("LIMA", "hey lily it got here!");

                /*
                String textFromFileString = readFromFile();
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                if(count%2!=0) {
                    tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
                tr.setId(100 + count);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //show data read from file
                dataReading = new TextView(this);
                dataReading.setId(200 + count);
                dataReading.setText(textFromFileString);
                dataReading.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                dataReading.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tr.addView(dataReading);
                //finally add data to table row
                t1.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                count++;
                Log.i("LIMA","Add row. There are now " + t1.getChildCount()+"rows");
                */
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
                Log.i("LIME","I pressed start!!!");
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                //gps.stopUsingGPS();
                Log.i("LIME","I pressed stop!!!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * writeToFile: writes data recordings of accelerometer to text file
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param z
     * @throws IOException
     */
    void writeToFile(String x, String y, String z) throws IOException {

        double latVal;
        double longVal;

        String s;

        //get exact instance of time in which call to write is being made
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        //create string to print to text using values in parameter.
        GPSTracker track = new GPSTracker(this);
        latVal = track.getLatitude();
        Log.i("test", "this is the latitude" + latVal);
        longVal = track.getLongitude();
        s = "Time: " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + " Coordinates: " + "x: " + x + " y: " + y + " z: " + z + " Latitude: " + latVal + " Longitude: " + longVal + "\n\r";

            //s = "Time: " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + " Coordinates: " + "x: " + x + " y: " + y + " z: " + z + "\n\r";
            //Log.i("shucks", "it never got the gps.");



        try {
            //append new string to file
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND | Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            //FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file, true);
            //BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            OutputStreamWriter bw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            bw.append(s);
            bw.append("\n\r");
            bw.close();
            Log.i("LIMA","IT GOT HERE 2");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
    private String readFromFile(){
        String ret = "";
        try {
            //open text file to read from
            InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //continue appending to stringBuilder until you've reached the end of file
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }
        return ret;
    }
     */
}
```

GPSTracker.java

```
package com.explorer.extractor;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    // saving the context for later use
    public final Context mContext;

    // if GPS is enabled
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    // if Network is enabled
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    // if Location co-ordinates are available using GPS or Network
    public boolean isLocationAvailable = false;

    // Location and co-ordinates coordinates
    Location mLocation;
    double mLatitude;
    double mLongitude;

    // Minimum time fluctuation for next update (in milliseconds)
    private static final long TIME = 0;
    // Minimum distance fluctuation for next update (in meters)
    private static final long DISTANCE = 0;

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    public LocationManager mLocationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    /**
     * Returs the Location
     *
     * @return Location or null if no location is found
     */
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {

            // Getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


            // If we are reaching this part, it means GPS was not able to fetch
            // any location
            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, TIME, DISTANCE, this);
                if (mLocationManager != null) {
                    mLocation = mLocationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (mLocation != null) {
                        mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                        isLocationAvailable = true; // setting a flag that
                        // location is available
                        return mLocation;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If reaching here means, we were not able to get location neither
            // from GPS not Network,

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // if reaching here means, location was not available, so setting the
        // flag as false
        isLocationAvailable = false;
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * get latitude
     *
     * @return latitude in double
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (mLocation != null) {
            mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
        }
        return mLatitude;
    }

    /**
     * get longitude
     *
     * @return longitude in double
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (mLocation != null) {
            mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        return mLongitude;
    }

    /**
     * close GPS to save battery
     */
    public void closeGPS() {
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updating the location when location changes
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared this permission in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: yes i included     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />